# Difference between dict_student[id] = [item[1]] and dict_student[id].append(item[1])?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to understand the following code. What's the difference between`dict_student[id] = [item[1]]` and `dict_student[id].append(item[1])`? Which part is adding the id if it's not found in the dictionary?

The code:

```
for item in items:
    id, score = item[0], item[1]
    if not id in dict_student:
      dict_student[id] = [item[1]]
    else:
      dict_student[id].append(item[1])
```

Comment: `dict_student[id].append(item[1])` requires that the entry already exist and is a list. `dict_student[id] = [item[1]]` creates\sets the entry.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean, would you mind clarifying?

Comment: I don't understand what you think each of them does, never mind why you think they're the "pretty much doing the same thing". But I would start with the observation that `append` means the same thing here that it does in ordinary English.

Comment: Hint: think about the condition used for the `if` statement. When the `append` version is used, is `id in dict_student`? So, what is being `append`ed to? When the other version is being used, is there anything to `append` to? So, do you understand why the code would not attempt to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a dictionary, an entry can be of type `list`. Use `append` to add to the list.

```
for item in items:
    id, score = item[0], item[1]
    if not id in dict_student:  #  if dictionary does not contain this key
      dict_student[id] = [item[1]]  # create the entry (a list)
    else:
      dict_student[id].append(item[1])  # add item to the existing list
```

Answer (score 1):

`dict_student[id] = [item[1]]` does not assumes that `id` is already a key of the dictionary. If `id` it's already a key in the dictionary you are changing whatever values it has and overwriting it with `[item[1]]`, if it isn't in the dictionary you are creating the key `id` and associate to that key the value `[item[1]]`

`dict_student[id].append(item[1])` assumes that the dictionary has already a key `id` in it, if it doesn't it will raise a `KeyError`, it further assumes that the object associated to the key `id` has an `append` method.